# Responsive site design widens profiles, pushing some info and controls farther to the right

Tags: bug, design, profile-page, navigation

I'm a member of a team on SO, so I have a preview of the responsive design that'll be coming soon to the rest of the network.  To reclaim more space, I'm using a [Stylish style](https://userstyles.org/styles/156837/so-channels-sidebar) to shrink the left nav until SE makes it collapsible as planned.  Even so, profiles on SO (main site and team) are now much wider, pushing information that used to be visible out of view.

Here is a screen shot from my MSE profile:

[image: MSE top of activity page]

In contrast, here's the top of a profile on SO.  Notice how much wider the big gray boxes (rep graph, badges) are compared to MSE, pushing the "stats" box (and user name!) out of view:

[image: SO top of activity page]

The push to the right doesn't just affect that stats box and recent rep (shown for SO below).  It also affects some handy controls.  MSE:

[image: badges]

And SO:

[image: recent rep, tags, badges all clipped]

There's plenty of room to show profiles at their current proportions; you can see in that first SO screen shot how little of the left nav is visible.  **I lost way more off the right side than the left nav consumed.**  Can we fix that?

To those who would say "get a bigger window" (or "don't zoom your fonts"): the whole point of responsive design is to fit within the space given.  That browser is about 1100px wide; it's not ridiculously small.

Comment: Does the problem go away if you click "Disable Responsiveness" on the bottom bar?

Comment: @SonictheInclusiveHedgehog huh, I didn't even see that!  But no, toggling it doesn't change the profile layout.  I wonder if they changed some baked-in numbers as part of doing the responsive design or something.

Comment: FYI, it is now possible to collapse the left nav. It's in your user profile settings, under the Preferences subtab (where you will also find the option to unlock the top bar when scrolling).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As a member of a Team, you should have access to collapsible left nav as of a few hours ago:

[image: screenshot of the "Hide left navigation" preference]

Does using that and disabling the Stylish overrides fix the issue? It might not, to be fair, but I'm cautiously optimistic.

Comment: Thank you!  Using that and disabling the style gives me the profile page I expected again.

Answer (score 2):

This is currently [status-bydesign](/questions/tagged/status-bydesign).

There's a [post from Joe Friend on Meta Stack Overflow](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/367724/responsive-design-is-enabled-for-teams-users) that explains the current status of the responsive design rollout. It specifically states that profile pages are not currently actively responsive:

> Pretty much everything else is non-responsive. This includes Ask a Question, profile pages and most moderator and review pages.

Pages where responsive design *is* active includes:

> ### Responsive pages or elements
>
> - Question pages
> - Question lists
> - Users and tags lists
> - Search results
> - Privileges
> - Help center
> - Top bar and footer
> - and a few other miscellaneous pages

This information was current as of May 11th.

I don't use anything to override the page styling like this but I do see side scrolling bars on profiles and the ask question page. If you don't (I can't tell from your screen shots) that may be a problem with the style.

Comment: I had side scrollbars too.  Thanks for this information; as a team member who is not an active SO user, I am not in the habit of trying to hunt down info that affects my team usage over there.  (Besides, volume...)